# Why does ReSharper w/ StyleCop put auto-generated members in the wrong places?

Tags: resharper, stylecop

I have the latest versions of R# and StyleCop installed.  I'm trying to figure out why my type members don't get put in the right places when I auto-generate them.  Also, if I change the access modifier from public to private, I want a shortcut that will re-order the methods in my class automatically.  Specifically:

1. When I auto-create a method using R#, I want it to be put in the correct order based on the access modifier (publics before privates, statics before instance, etc.)
2. When I auto-create a field using R#, I don't want blank lines in between the fields (team coding rule)
3. I want a keyboard shortcut for re-ordering methods that are out-of-order

Comment: I'm not aware of a setting to put generated members in a specific order; but, you can you reformat code to have it re-order them in an order you prefer.